# QTextBrowser: How to represent images copied to the clipboard by custom text?

Tags: image, qt, clipboard, qt5, representation

Consider the following code:

```
QTextDocument * doc = ui->textBrowser->document();
doc->addResource(QTextDocument::ImageResource, QUrl("img://smiley"), QImage("happy.png"));
QTextCursor cursor = ui->textBrowser->textCursor();
cursor.insertHtml("Sample text ");
cursor.insertImage("img://smiley");
ui->textBrowser->setTextCursor(cursor);
```

(ui->textBrowser is a pointer to a QTextBrowser object)

When I copy the image to the clipboard, it is represented by an object replacement character (U+FFFC). Is it possible to change this behavior and save e.g. ":-)" instead?

Note that I am using Qt 5.2, so it's fine to use any functions introduced in Qt 5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no simple way. In a web browser `alt` attribute would help, but Qt doesn't support it.

You can track clipboard's changes and correct its content.

Initialization:

```
QClipboard* clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
connect(clipboard, SIGNAL(changed(QClipboard::Mode)),
        this, SLOT(clipboard_changed()));
```

Clipboard correction (example):

```
void MainWindow::clipboard_changed() {
  QClipboard* clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
  const QMimeData* data = clipboard->mimeData();
  QString html = data->html();
  if (html.contains("<img src=\"img://smiley\" />")) {
    QString new_html = html;
    new_html.replace("<img src=\"img://smiley\" />", ":-)");
    QTextDocument doc;
    doc.setHtml(new_html);
    QString text = doc.toPlainText();
    if (text != data->text()) {
      QMimeData* new_data = new QMimeData();
      new_data->setHtml(html);
      new_data->setText(doc.toPlainText());
      clipboard->setMimeData(new_data);
    }
  }
}
```

Of course you will need more sophisticated implementation for a real program.

I use `QTextDocument` just to convert HTML to plain text.